# Querying Custom Meta data with Like and IN operator

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

I like to query Custom-metadata multiple values with like operator. I am able to successfully query with a single like i.e. 
`[... From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like 'EmailToSign%' ...]` //returns few records.

But I like to add more filter on Label column i.e.
`[... From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like 'EmailToSign%' OR Label Like 'SendCopy%'...]` and generates an error.

Failed attempt-1:

```
Set<String> voiceMailOptions = new Set<String>{'EmailToSign%', 'SendCopy%'};
[... From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like : voiceMailOptions order by Label ASC]; //returns no row though there are values
```

Failed attempt-2:

```
[..From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like 'EmailToSign%' OR Label Like 'SendCopy%' order by Label ASC]; //returns no row though there are values
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks, Mahesh.

Comment: We can use the following operators with SOQL over custom metadata types.
`IN and NOT IN
=, >, >=, <, <=, and !=
LIKE, including wild cards
AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt will not work with Custom Metadata and Objects as well, because like accepts only one argument at a time. In the case of Objects, you can use an `OR` operator.

The second attempt works with Objects and unfortunately does not work with Custom Metadata.

> But as it's a custom metadata object you can write two queries to get
>   the data and combine the result, as querries against Metadata objects
>   are not counted in SOQL Governor Limits.
>
> Please note that the limit on the number of rows in the query still
>   applies here.

```
// Query 1
List<City_Setting__mdt> firstRes = [... From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like 'EmailToSign%' ...];
// Query 2
List<City_Setting__mdt> secRes = [... From City_Setting__mdt where Label Like 'SendCopy%' ...];
// Combine the result in a list.
List<City_Setting__mdt> combineRes = firstRes.addAll(secRes);
```